# inline definition of function - external or internal linkage

Tags: c++

In the following transactional units:

```
//1.cpp
#include<iostream>

extern void calll();

inline void fun()
{
    std::cout<<"in fun 1\n";
}

int main()
{
    fun();
    calll();
    return 0;
}




//2.cpp
#include<iostream>

inline void fun()
{
    int i=123;                  //random un-used variable
    char c= 99;                 //random un-used variable
    std::cout<<"in fun 2\n";
}

void calll()
{
    fun();
}
```

**case 1 -> ** on compiling it like `g++ 1.cpp 2.cpp` the output is: 
    `in fun 1
     in fun 1`

**case 2 -> ** on compiling it with `g++ 2.cpp 1.cpp` the output is:
    `in fun 2
     in fun 2`

In both case *1* and *2* one of the call to function `fun()` is running the reference to the definition of `fun()` from the transactional unit whose `.cpp` file
is mentioned first in compilation which indicates that the `inline` has by default external linkage as single definition works in both object files without using `extern` declaration
- on commenting or deleting the definition of `inline void fun()` in either **1.cpp** or **2.cpp** the compiler throws an error that `fun() has not been defined` which means that the 
linker links the first definition of `fun()` it finds and the function calling the `inline void fun()` uses that definition but they also require a definition 
which is present in their transactional unit even when that definition is not used. Here I believe the definition of `fun` actually used in calls by either 
`main` or `calll` is having external linkcage - as no inline (separate definition) has been generated for the individual object files.

If this above observation is true then why does the compiler require a definition in individual object files when it uses a single definition?
Is it because if the file is compiled in the way that in **case 1** or **case 2** there still is a chance of functions actually getting inlined 
when `-O2` is used to compile and each object file will have to use their own definition of `inline void fun()`?

What exactly will guarantees whether function will be inlined or not?

Comment: The compiler does not require that the definition of a function is in both compilation units. It only needs their declaration to compile. But in the linking step at least one of them is required to have the definition.  But if you have the definition in multiple compilation units, then you are required to define them as `inline` and if you do so you are required to guarantee that they are equal.

Comment: Your example contains One Definition Rule (ORD) violation, and is therefore ill-formed, no diagnostic required.

Comment: @t.niese The definition is required if marked inline. [dcl.inline]/6: "An inline function or variable shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example actually violates the [one definition rule](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). In short, with an `inline` function you're allowed to have multiple definitions provided that each one:

- is in a different translation unit (which you do have)
- each definition has the same sequence of tokens (which you clearly do not)

So this is actually UB.

`inline` functions require there to be a definition in every translation unit where they are ODR used, so they can be completely defined in a header without a compilation unit for example.

This is not the same as "inlining" a function. `inline` only implies that the function is defined "in-line" with it's declaration. Any function will or will not be inlined at the discretion of your compiler.

Comment: Even if I remove unused random variables to make both of the object files have the same sequence of tokens the behaviour remains the same.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus What behaviour remains the same? They can't continue outputting different strings.

Comment: @aschepler I mentioned my comment to ask if the UB Artyer has mentioned will stop.

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus `"in fun 2\n"` is a different token from `"in fun 1\n"` if you have those 2 strings

Comment: Or if your asking why you still need both the definitions it's because both translation units ODR-use it

Comment: So its better to just put the definition into a header?